# C6H5CO2H dimerization in Benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond

Why does $\ce{C6H5COOH}$ in benzene form dimers? Also why only in benzene, why not in other solvents such as water?

In general, what are the properties of compounds which form dimers or polymers in benzene?

Comment: Hint: somehow it didn't occur to you that your asking about hydrogen bonds.

Comment: Yes, but why in benzene, and why not in water?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboxylic_acid

Comment: I see. So they will form dimers in non-polar solvents. 
Can you explain this please? "whereas higher carboxylic acids are less soluble due to the increasing hydrophobic nature of the alkyl chain."
Thanks!

Comment: That should be an entirely separate question. However, if you bear in mind that water is a pretty polar solvent, and alkyl groups are non-polar (hydrophobic basically means non-polar), I suppose you could deduce the answer.

Comment: Is it because since the salt is non-polar, water is unable to break it. But then how does Benzene dissolve the salt? What exactly is meant by solubility in Benzene?

Comment: Note that the acetic acid forms the dimer even in gaseous phase, it is not benzene specific. The acid does not form dimers, if the solvent is able to form strong enough hydrogen bonds so the molecules of the acid preferably  bonds with the solvent.

Answer (score 3):

In polar solvents such as water, the water molecules will solvate the carboxylic acid. Thus, hydrogen bonds will form between the 2 molecules and the carboxylic acid will dissolve.

The water is in large excess as it is the solvent so it will solvate most of the carboxylic acid molecules.

In a non-polar solvent such as benzene, no such hydrogen bonds can take place with the carboxylic acid and benzene molecules. As a result, the carboxylic acids simply interact with themselves and form dimers.